# How can i associate Winform's Progress Bar changes with other function

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have a progress bar which codes in below. I find this code from net. i really want to do when i click one button this button do some process and i count it.how can i understand when is there any changes in ReadExistingExcel fucnc this. This  function is in other class and there are  a lot of loop in this function

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            Class1 yeni = new Class1();
            yeni.Update();
        }

        public  void  UpdateMyProgressBar(int i)
        {
            progressBar1.Value=i;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);

        }



        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

    }
```

other class

```
 public class Class1
    {
        public void Update()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Form1 ins = new Form1();
                ins.UpdateMyProgressBar(i); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code stand now the `Form1` class creates a new instance of `Class1` which then, inside the `Update` method, creates 100 new instances of `Form1`. It's not getting a reference to the existing form. And that's your problem.

Try changing your `Class1` code like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
    }

    private Form1 _form1;

    public void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            _form1.UpdateMyProgressBar(i); 
        }
    }
}
```

Then change `Form1` like this:

```
   private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
       Class1 yeni = new Class1(this);
       yeni.Update();
   }

   public  void  UpdateMyProgressBar(int i)
   {
       backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it sounds like you just need to have a public void to update the progressbar value.

```
public void UpdateProgressBar(int val)
{
   progressBar1.Value = val;
}
```

This can then be called from your other classes by referring to your current class.
So if your current class is called Class1 and you want to call it from Class10 you would simply do
    Class1.UpdateProgressBar(10);

Comment: hi i try this solution. i call UpdateProgressBar method from  other  class  and i can't see any changes in progressbar.loops values set progressbar value but it couldn't work